# querying 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

good day, i have a problem in querying in 2 mysql table.

table 1

```
c_id     c_name
**-----------------**
 1      blah,blah
 2      hey
```

table 2

```
m_id    c_id    m_name
-----------------------
 1       1     some_name
 2       1     some-name
 3       1     some/name
 4       1     some.name
 5       2     name.some
 6       2     name-some
```

i wanted the display to be like this:

```
c_id     c_name       m_name
-----------------------------
 1     blah,blah     some_name
                     some-name
                     some/name
                     some.name
 2     hey           name.some
                     name-some
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.c_id, a.c_name, 
group_concat(b.m_name SEPARATOR '<br/>') as m_name from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.c_id = b.c_id
group by a.c_id;
```

***[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bab3/4)***

Use m_name bind to a label. It will come with line breaks

Answer (score 1):

This query will output exactly what you want :

```
select case when first.m_id is null then ' ' else t1.c_id end c_id, 
       case when first.m_id is null then ' ' else t1.c_name end c_name, 
       m_name
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.c_id = t2.c_id
left outer join (
    select m_id,t1.c_id, t1.c_name, min(m_name)
    from Table1 t1
    inner join Table2 t2 on t1.c_id = t2.c_id
    group by t1.c_id, t1.c_name) first on t2.m_id = first.m_id  
order by t1.c_id, t2.m_id
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bab3/16/0

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.c_id, a.c_name, b.m_name from  table1 a left join table2 b on a.c_id  = b.c_id;
```

Comment: expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to get the results of both tables together:

```
select c_id, c_name, m_name from table1 as x left outer join table2 as y on x.c_id = y.c_id;
```

Comment: What is the variable x and y? thanks, I'm really new at this.

Comment: Its not variable. Just alias for table

Comment: the query returns 4 rows, but what I'm trying to achieve is to return 2 rows just like the above example..

Comment: What is purpose of this output?

Comment: Yeah that seems like a waste - if "group by' doesn't cut it or you can't do it in your native programming language then we're at a loss here